Why are my raspberry leaves drying up but still green?
Raspberry plants have leaves that start to dry and curl up. The leaves are crisp and crinkly. It starts at the leaf edge and eventually the whole leaf is dried up. I planted these last year and didn’t have this problem.  This is in a small back-yard garden that previously grew squash and peas.
I know someone else with this same problem on one plant (they don’t know what it is either). That plant produces less and the fruit is often deformed. This has happened multiple seasons to them, to that same plant.
I’ve don’t see any visible bugs on the leaves.
I have some photos of the front and back of a few affected ones.




Possible herbicide drift...
